# Having trouble refactoring an IEnumerator method with multiple yields

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, yield-return, ienumerator

The gist of my code is as follows:

```
// Play the first beat
audio.PlayOneShot(beat);

// Show 1st heartbeat border flash
TweenAlpha.Begin(heartbeatPanel.gameObject, 0.1f, currentStress);
yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
TweenAlpha.Begin(heartbeatPanel.gameObject, 0.5f, 0);

yield return new WaitForSeconds(interval);

// Play the second beat
audio.PlayOneShot(beat);

// Show 2nd heartbeat border flash
TweenAlpha.Begin(heartbeatPanel.gameObject, 0.1f, currentStress);
yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
TweenAlpha.Begin(heartbeatPanel.gameObject, 0.5f, 0);

yield return new WaitForSeconds(interval * 2);
```

---

Now I want to split the above code into a single IEnumerator method with 2 calls.

This is what I came up with:

```
StartCoroutine(PlayBeat(currentStress, interval));
StartCoroutine(PlayBeat(currentStress, interval * 2));

// ...

IEnumerator PlayBeat(float currentStress, float interval)
{
     audio.PlayOneShot(beat);

     TweenAlpha.Begin(heartbeatPanel.gameObject, 0.1f, currentStress);
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
     TweenAlpha.Begin(heartbeatPanel.gameObject, 0.5f, 0);

     yield return new WaitForSeconds(interval);
}
```

The problem with this is that instead of the beats sounding with their correct interval, both beats sounded at the the same time and because I have these calls in an infinite loop, Unity crashed because the intervals are not being considered.

**What's the best way to extract my two repetitive blocks of code above into a single IEnumerator method?**

Comment: Your current code looks fine (at least, without seeing `StartCoroutine`) - what's the problem?

Comment: Can you please be more specific than "it doesn't work" when describing the problem.

Comment: Am I right that you hear the two beats at once?

Comment: @EamonNerbonne: The problem with my first block of code is that I have repeated code for sounding the beats, and I want to extract that into its own method.

Comment: @ChrisF: I thought that since my issue is trivial to a Unity developer, there was no need to go in depth on how exactly the code did not perform.

Comment: @Kay: No, the beats are separated with an interval.

Comment: @AndreasGrech How do you know that it's trivial? It's always good to explain what exactly is the problem, “it doesn't work” is not very useful.

Comment: Updated the question to better define the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unity3d's Coroutines can be nested.  To wait for a nested coroutine you need to yield it.  So your function `PlayBeat` is fine; you just need to start it in a way that unity3d understands to mean "wait until complete".  Your example would then look as follows:

```
yield return StartCoroutine(PlayBeat(currentStress, interval));
yield return StartCoroutine(PlayBeat(currentStress, interval * 2));
```

It's uncanny how similar that looks to C# 5's async/await.  At some level this is unsurprising since they're both compiler-transformed "coroutine" statemachines - but it's still neat to see the similarity.